# close other gridview panel when I open one of them

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview within gridview. Currently when I click on one panel it opens it and when I click on another it opens another one but it does not close one which was opened earlier. I want only one panel to be opened at a time.

```
 <%--INSTITUTION PANEL START--%>
 <div class="panel panel-danger">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>
                            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCreateInstitution" runat="server" OnClick="lnkCreateInstitution_Click">Create New Institution</asp:LinkButton>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <asp:GridView ID="dgInstitute" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0"
                            CellSpacing="0" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" PageSize="100" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-responsive table-bordered"
                            Visible="true" UseAccessibleHeader="true" OnRowCreated="dgInstitute_RowCreated"
                            OnDataBound="dgInstitute_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="dgInstitute_RowDataBound">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id" DataField="refGroupId" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridHeader panel-default"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridHeader panel-default">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                        <asp:Button ID="btnInstituteName" Text='<%#Eval("refValues") %>' CssClass="btn btn-Institute"
                                                            runat="server" OnClick="btnInstituteName_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("refGroupId") %>' />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            <%--PROGRAM PANEL START--%>
                                              <asp:Panel ID="programPanel" runat="server" class="hidden">
                                                <div id="pnlProgramBody" runat="server" class="panel-body">
                                                    <h5>
                                                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCreateProgram" runat="server" OnClick="lnkCreateProgram_Click">Create New Program</asp:LinkButton></h5>
                                                    <asp:GridView ID="dgProgram" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0"
                                                        CellSpacing="0" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" PageSize="100" Width="100%"
                                                        OnRowDataBound="dgProgram_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="dgProgram_RowCreated" CssClass="table table-responsive table-bordered zero-margin-table"
                                                        Visible="true" UseAccessibleHeader="true">
                                                        <Columns>
                                                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id" DataField="refGroupId" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="80%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridHeader panel-default"></asp:BoundField>
                                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridHeader panel-default" ShowHeader="false" HeaderStyle-Width='20%'>
                                                                <ItemTemplate>

                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnProgram" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-embossed" runat="server"
                                                                        Text='<%#Eval("refValues") %>'
                                                                        OnClick="btnProgram_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("refGroupId") %>' />
                                                             </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>

                                                        </Columns>
                                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="panel-default"></HeaderStyle>
                                                        <RowStyle CssClass=""></RowStyle>
                                                    </asp:GridView>
                                                </div>
                                            </asp:Panel>
                                            <%--PROGRAM PANEL END--%>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="panel-default"></HeaderStyle>
                            <RowStyle CssClass=""></RowStyle>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <%--INSTITUTION PANEL END--%>
```

here Institute is first panel which contains Institute names as button. It comes from database and binds on the gridview dgInstitute. This gridView contains second panel which which has list of programs and it also comes from database. Each institute contains few programs.

```
   protected void dgInstitute_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        #region VISIBLE FALSE

        e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;

        #endregion           
    }

    protected void dgInstitute_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region VISBLE FALSE

        dgInstitute.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Visible = false;

        #endregion
    }

    protected void dgInstitute_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        #region BIND PROGRAM VALUES

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView nestedGridView = e.Row.FindControl("dgProgram") as GridView;
            dsResult = new System.Data.DataSet();
            parentId = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
            dsResult = getProgram(parentId);

            nestedGridView.DataSource = dsResult;
            nestedGridView.DataBind();

            nestedGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Visible = false;
            nestedGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        }

        #endregion
    }

   protected void btnInstituteName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region SHOW/HIDE PRORAMS

        Button instituteButton = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow programGrid = (GridViewRow)instituteButton.NamingContainer;

        Panel programPanel = programGrid.FindControl("programPanel") as Panel;

        if (programPanel.Attributes["class"] == "hidden")
        {
            programPanel.Attributes["class"] = "visible";
        }

        else
        {
            programPanel.Attributes["class"] = "hidden";
        }

        #endregion

    }

       protected void dgProgram_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        #region VISIBLE FALSE

        e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;

        #endregion           
    }
```

Now when I click on an Institute it opens the panel to show the program panel with the grid containing program list and when I click same panel again it closes it. So that works perfectly. But When one program panel is open for a specific institute, and I click on another institute button then it should close other open program panels.

Any suggestions. i am using asp .net panel and gridview combination because I have to perform many tasks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Client side Expand Collapse functionality using jQuery and JavaScript**

For Expand and Collapse of the Child GridViews I have made use of jQuery

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"
    DataKeyNames="CustomerID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderId" HeaderText="Order Id" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Date" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
</script>
```